# How to create a CustomMapping transform for data in the middle of the pipeline?

Tags: ml.net

I have a pipeline for processing text and I'd like to add a stemming step.

```
var textPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Text.NormalizeText("Text", "Html", Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Text.TextNormalizingEstimator.CaseMode.Lower, false, false, false)
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.DropColumns("Html"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.TokenizeIntoWords("Tokens", "Text"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.RemoveDefaultStopWords("Tokens", language: StopWordsRemovingEstimator.Language.English));
-->stemming<--
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Tokens"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.ProduceNgrams("Tokens"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.LatentDirichletAllocation("Features", "Tokens", numberOfTopics: 20));
```

Between `RemoveDefaultStopWords` and `MapValueToKey`, I'd like to call a `CustomMapping` action, but all the samples I've seen work from data that was loaded into the initial dataview and not data created by stages in the pipeline.

How do I create an Action<> that takes the vector of strings and returns a new vector of strings?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of playing around,

```
Action<HtmlRaw, StemmedOutput> mapping = (input, output) => output.StemmedTokens = input.Tokens.Select(t => stemmer.Stem(t).Value).ToArray();
```

It was just a matter of creating new classes and matching property names to the column names used in the pipeline.